# Spring injects a bean other than what is specified in @Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, properties-file, spring-annotations

Recently I've made an error while wiring beans in Spring that caused a behaviour that I'm unable to replicate. Instead of a property sourced with `@Value` getting injected into `Stuff` (see the complete demo code below) a value of another bean of type `String` defined in `@Configuration` was used when the application was deployed.

What I find puzzling is that everything works as expected when running locally (including the unit test), the output is `foo` not `kaboom`, and that this 'bean swap' happened at all when deployed rather than 'no qualifying bean' error.

The commented out line shows the fix which I think makes the configuration similar to what is in [the manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html).

What is the problem with my set-up? What would make the code as shown (i.e. without the fix) use `kaboom` `String` rather than `foo` property?

```kotlin
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
open class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

```kotlin
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Configuration
open class Config {

    // ...beans of types other than String in original code...

    @Bean
    open fun beanBomb(): String {
        return "kaboom"
    }

    @Bean
    // fix:
    // @Value("\${stuff}")
    open fun beanStuff(stuff: String): Stuff {
        return Stuff(stuff)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class Stuff(@Value("\${stuff}") val stuff: String)
```

```kotlin
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct

@Component
class Init {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var stuff: Stuff

    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        println("stuff: " + stuff.stuff)
    }
}
```

```
// application.properties
stuff=foo
```

```kotlin
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"stuff=testFoo"})
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @SpyBean
    private Stuff stuff;

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertEquals("testFoo", stuff.getStuff());
    }

}
```

Also, is the `@Value` annotation in `Stuff` necessary once the fix has been applied? If I uncomment the fix, remove `@Value` from `Stuff` and add the following annotation to the test class the test passes:

```kotlin
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config.class})
```

but when I run the app it prints `kaboom`...

Comment: What is the point of placing the `@Component` annotation on `Stuff` class and at the same time defining it in the java configuration (the method with a `@Bean` annotation)?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the order in which the bean is being created. if the bean is created before than in my view the Spring IoC container inject the value by type i.e. `kaboom` and since the Bean of any type is singleton by default, the instance of `Stuff` won't come into effect even though it is annotated with `@component`.

In your test you're loading the configuration manually where the bean of `Stuff` defined in `Config` is being injected not the `Stuff` annotated with `@component`.

Comment: So the problem with original code is that I create the bean `Stuff` in two places (`@Bean` vs `@Component`), with one getting the argument from `@Value` annotation and the other from the `String` bean created in `Config`. It so happens that when I run locally Spring creates the `@Component` annotated `Stuff` with `stuff` coming from `@Value`, whereas when the app was deployed Spring must have created the `@Bean` annotated `Stuff` with `stuff` coming from `beanBomb()`. Correct? 

If so it's a shame that Spring doesn't warn of multiple bean declarations, instead just picks any from the lot.

Comment: Yeah it could be.. you can add a debugger point or add some log message just for the purpose of identifying to order the creation of bean and other options is to use `@Priority` or `@order` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the annotation needs to go on the parameter not the function.
In your way Spring is looking for a bean that meets the Type of `String` and there is a bean of Type `String` produced by the function `beanBomb()`. If you move the annotation like this it should remove the ambiguity.

```kotlin
    @Bean
    open fun beanStuff(@Value("\${stuff}") stuff: String): Stuff {
        return Stuff(stuff)
    }
```

I would add tho, that it's a bit unusual to have a bean of Type `String`, but I suppose if you don't want to use property/yaml files it would allow you to change a `String` based on profile.